# DOMPDF invoices with multiple pages

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm creating invoices using DOMPDF. What I need is to have the content of the invoice flow on as many pages as needed and have the total $ due at the bottom of the invoice.

I first tried having a fixed height div with an absolute-positioned footer, but obviously my invoice details can extend onto the footer.

What I need is to have a min-height for my main div and add a padding at the bottom of the said div for my footer, but min-height doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried making my whole page into a table, but I don't want my table rows to split onto multiple pages (so as to keep all my totals together on the same page.)

Any solutions ?

***EDIT***

Sample HTML (absolute positioning) :

```
<div id="main" style="height:10in;width:7in;position:relative;">
    <!-- header is here, all OK -->
    <!-- content, dynamic height -->
    <!-- footer -->
</div>
```

Sample HTML (tables) :

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr><!-- header --></tr>
  <tr><!-- content --></tr>
  <tr><!-- footer --></tr>
</table>
```

The footer should never be split, and at the end of the document. If the content fills the page, the footer should be at the end of the page.

Comment: Having trouble visualizing this, can you post a sample HTML doc?

Comment: I've added a visual aid which should help you see the general picture.

Comment: Does it matter where on the page the footer is? I.e. should it be just after the content, or could it be at the bottom of the page regardless of how far down the content comes?

Comment: Also, yes, min-height doesn't work right now.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to keep in mind is to avoid nested tables (in case you're using table layouts). Adding `<table>` inside another table's `<td>` gives rise to many pdf layout issues. All the tables' parents should be a `<div>` or a `<body>` and DOMPDF can correctly interpret the layout.

Comment: This is an excellent point. I haven't touched this in the past 8 years, but I think this is an important point to take into consideration. If I were to do it today, I would try flexbox (if supported) but I would most certainly do as you suggested and stick to div's. Thanks for your input, will probably help someone else!

Comment: After doing a lot of research and work on this I wasn't able to sort this issue out, actually my PDF generated was not rendering all the pages and was breaking after the second page, turns out the issue was nested tables, removing nested tables worked like a charm, Thanks you !!

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution would be to use `page-break-before: avoid` on the footer. This would only provide a minimum of coverage under your scenario (i.e. only a single table row would be pulled with it), but at least the footer wouldn't be solo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style>
    div { width: 100%; margin: .25em; }
    span { width: 33%; display: inline-block; }
    div#footer { text-align: right; border-top: 1px solid black; page-break-before: avoid; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div><span>Count</span><span>Item</span><span>Item Total</span></div>
  <div><span>1</span><span>widget</span><span>X.XX</span></div>
  <div><span>1</span><span>widget</span><span>X.XX</span></div>
  ...
  <div><span>1</span><span>widget</span><span>X.XX</span></div>
  <div><span>1</span><span>widget</span><span>X.XX</span></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Total: X.XX</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately page-break-before doesn't work well on tables. To provide a work around in this situation I'll begin with an assumption: the footer can be at the very bottom of the page, regardless of how far down the content comes.

In this case you can basically work around the problem because of a quirk in how dompdf processes document content. Namely, elements are rendered as they are encountered. So a fixed-position element is rendered on pages starting with the page on which it is encountered. It will not appear on previous pages.

This is a quirk up to v0.6.0 and may change in the future.

So you can place your footer at the end of the document using `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` with a page margin into which you shift the footer. Something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style>
    @page { margin: 1in; }
    table { width: 100%; }
    div#footer { width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: -.35in; text-align: right; border-top: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr><td>Count</td><td>Item</td><td>Item Total</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>widget</td><td>X.XX</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>widget</td><td>X.XX</td></tr>
  ...
  <tr><td>1</td><td>widget</td><td>X.XX</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>widget</td><td>X.XX</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="footer">
  <p>Total: X.XX</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

With the above code the footer will always appear on the last page at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Hi, I am using `dompdf` as well and I noticed the rendering download of PDF is pretty slow when generating a 1 page invoice page with tables. May I know how to improve the load time?

Comment: Also, once I downloaded the invoice in pdf, the alignment are all wrong and doesn't look as what I did with in my view file. My invoice is just using some bootstrap for table and some styling.

Comment: @LordJesus you should go ahead and start a new question (ideally one per issue you're having). It's hard to get enough details in comments without resorting to a discussion, which is not really how StackOverflow is intended to be used.

Comment: I believed I have. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832542/laravel-dompdf-render-not-correctly